# array of struct using c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm making an ice cream maker using c# in visual studio 2013
first of all when the ice cream maker loaded, the program should construct 2 records.. one for each flavour of ice-cream and the other one for ice cream toppings

and I've done that by creating a new class and write the attribute for each record like so:

```
namespace IceCreamMaker {

class Class1
{

    public class flavour
    {
        public string flavour_name { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public int Available_quantity { get; set; }

        public flavour(string flavour_name, double Price1, int Available_quantity)
        {
            flavour_name = flavour_name;
            Price = Price1;
            Available_quantity = Available_quantity;
        }
    }

    public class topping
    {
        public string Topping_type { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }

        public topping(string Topping_type, double Price2)
        {
            Topping_type = Topping_type;
            Price = Price2;
        }
    }

}
```

**now the problem is in this sentence :**

declare and construct two arrays of Struct as public
variables; one for flavours and the other for toppings.

**I didn't understand what should I do?**

Comment: see class vs struct: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173109.aspx

Comment: There is too little information here to help you concretely. Also, I'm not sure whether class assignments are even on topic. Stack Overflow is not the right place to ask this.

Comment: I'm not asking you to solve the assignment!! I just needed some explanation, so that I can solve it myself!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to declare your flavour and topping classes as structs instead. Structs in c# are similar to classes except they are passed by value rather than by reference. Then declare two arrays of these types inside your outer class. Finally define a constructor for the outer class and construct both of the arrays.

```
namespace IceCreamMaker {

class Class1
{

    public struct flavour
    {
        public string flavour_name { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public int Available_quantity { get; set; }

        public flavour(string flavour_name, double Price1, int  Available_quantity)
        {
            flavour_name = flavour_name;
            Price = Price1;
            Available_quantity = Available_quantity;
        }
    }

    public struct topping
    {
        public string Topping_type { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }

        public topping(string Topping_type, double Price2)
        {
            Topping_type = Topping_type;
            Price = Price2;
        }
    }

    public flavour flavours[];
    public topping toppings[];

    public Class1()
    {
        flavours = new flavour[50];
        toppings = new topping[50];
    }

}
```